# Getting POST data in Magento observer

Tags: php, magento

So, I'm struggling with this, I've got an observer set up to trigger whenever customer/account/login is hit. Firebug clearly shows that I'm POSTing data to this URL and I'm not able to read said POST data in my observer method.

Observer method:

```
public function checkCustomerLogin($observer) {
    Mage::log("event observed");
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    Mage::log(print_r($controller->getRequest()->getPost(), true));
    return $this;
}
```

Example log result:

```
2014-03-11T11:46:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): event observed
2014-03-11T11:46:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)
```

My observer is configured to trigger on `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_login`. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here seeing as how I just can't get my POST data (I've tried a few other desperate approaches but from what I can tell this is how you're "supposed" to get a controller and the POST data in an observer method).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()`

It will return array of all parameters sent to called controller's action

Hope this helps you

Comment: Tried that one just now, still just an empty array.

Comment: Try Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());

and Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());

and check log that your desired controller is trapped by observer or not.

Comment: Controller name is `account` and action name is `login`.

Comment: You will not find any post data here, since in account controller's login action, no values are passed in post.

You should use your observer for loginPostAction (I think) to get values in params.

Comment: Ah, `loginPost`, I keep forgetting that one exists. That worked a lot better.

Comment: thank you, working for me using `newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after` event

Answer (score 6):

instead of controller use app so

instead of

```
Mage::log(print_r($controller->getRequest()->getPost(), true));
```

change to

```
Mage::log(print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost(), true));
```

So that instead of controller you are using $app to get post details.